# why do mathematical operators interact with strings in sql

Tags: mysql, operators

Say I use the sql query:

```
select * from table t where t.name = "adam" and t.age > 10;
```

and in the column "age", there is more than just integer values. There are also values "old", "young", etc...

The result of this query would be all adam's with an age older than 10, but also all adam's with an age equal to one of the string values "old", "young", etc...

Why is this?

Comment: Rule 1, learned in 1976: a field should not be used for more than one purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is MySQLs [Type Conversion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)
which occurs implicit when you apply operators to data/columns of different types.

To the example you posted: It's generally considered bad practice to save data of different types/meanings in the same field.

I'd set the type of your 'age' column to 'int', and make it nullable. Then add another column named `about_age` which could be an ENUM with the values `old` and `young`. Whenever the 'age' column is `NULL`, your application can check the the `about_age` column. Only with this way, it's completely clear what your data means.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. I'll restructure the database to not have data of multiple types in the same field.